# Status bar blocking UI

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, bounds

I'm running code from xcode on my iPhone. The blue status bar, saying it has an connection to xcode, is allway there.

1. Does it have to be there, in order to program to the phone?
2. Is there a way to set the views bounds to the visible part of the screen? Maybe a way (or what is best practice) to update the visible bounds of the screen, when a change in the status bar occurs, so that it changes the bounds for all view controllers?

I hope this isn't a too trivial question, howeven i havn't been able to solve it by searching.

[image]

Comment: Do you have a screenshot of what you're describing?

Comment: Yeah, would be nice, TBH I have no clue what you might experience

Comment: sorry, it's added now..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That blue notification bar is showing because you are sharing an internet connection with your computer. Not because you are connected to Xcode. Turn off your Personal Hotspot in your devices settings.

**On your device** navigate to: Settings > Cellular > Turn off Personal Hotspot

You can get the height of the status bar like so:

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarFrame.size.height
```

Using Auto Layout to deal with any status bar changes would be easiest in my opinion. `Pin` your `UIView` to the bottom of your status bar in Interface Builder.

Comment: okay, so do I have to ajust every view controllers frame by this method, or is there a universal way to change alle the view controllers views to this frame?

Comment: @Rapsefar I've edited my answer. Using Auto Layout will be your easiest option. Add the code you are using to size your `ViewControllers` to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Select the View Controller and uncheck the box saying "Under the Topbar". That way your views should not go under the status bar, but the blue bar in your screen shot is not because of the status bar as others have indicated.

[image]

Comment: I was looking for something like this, but it doesn't resolve my problem. I'm setting the the frame of the imageview, by using the the view controllers views bounds, and this seems still to point to some point under the blue bar...

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question: No, the blue bar does not have to be there. In fact, it is not related to Xcode in any way, it just says, that your computer uses the internet connection of your iPhone. To turn this off, go to Settings>Personal Hotspot and switch it off.